# A late riley Halloween riddle

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

Sorry, I missed Halloween by 1 month

> My prefix is christmas-with-e,
> My suffix you do every day.
> My infix is latin-infinitive-ending,
> My whole with magic is Ha-llo-ween

Somehow this is not rhyming :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word is

> '**TREAT**'

---

My prefix is christmas-with-e,

> 'Tre' + e = **Tree** as in christmas tree

My suffix you do every day.

> We '**eat**' every day

My infix is latin-infinitive,

> '**re**' is a [latin infinitive](https://www.thoughtco.com/latin-verbs-infinitives-112183#:%7E:text=Latin%20Infinitive%20Basics&text=The%20second%20entry%E2%80%94usually%20abbreviated,plus%20whatever%20the%20verb%20means.)

My whole with magic is Ha-llo-ween

> 'Trick or **Treat**' is to do with Halloween

Comment: So fast? Yes your right. Just the latin infinitive I meant "re" ending, for verbs.

Comment: @math yeah I was a bit unsure about which part you were referring too, as none of the infiixes seem to be perfect matches. 're' itself isnt even an infinitive, but 'are', 'ire' etc are. I would probably have tried to think of a better clue for that one

Comment: Yes, sorry. Shall I add a clue for further readers?

Comment: @math no don't worry about it now, but for instacne searching 're' latin infinitive doesn't actually come up with a proper result, so that would be a good indicator it might be a bit vague

Comment: 're', along with 'er' and 'ir' is a proper french infinitive though :)